# Custom solution to implement callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Is it possible to wrap functions like `setTimeout` and then fire callback. Like in jQuery `$(selector).on('action', callback)`.

```
var obj = {
   mth1: function (callback) {
       //----need to wrap to something
          setTimeout(function () { console.log("1"); }, 1000);
          console.log('2');
       //----
       // callback;
   }
};
function callback() {
   console.log('3');
};
(function () { obj.mth1(callback); }) ();
```

What I need:

```
2
1
3
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply run `callback()` after `console.log(1)` in the `setTimeout` function?

Comment: That is specific case, below i wrote another situations, i can repost: But imagine that will be another code instead of setTimeout, which will return pdf or error message (if fail on generating pdf). So i need to wait while response will come back and if response is OK - than call downloading dialog, else if response return 500 - show error message in label. I can`t figure it out how to call downloading dialog if pdf returned from ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add it at the end of your function inside the setTimout

```
// *snip*
setTimeout(function () { 
    console.log("1");
    callback();
}, 1000);
// *snip*
```

Comment: But imagine that will be another code instead of setTimeout, which will return pdf or error message (if fail on generating pdf). So i need to wait while response will come back and if response is OK - than call downloading dialog, else if response return 500 - show error message in label. I can`t figure it out how to call downloading dialog if pdf returned from ajax

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking for. Just make sure it is a function and call it:

```
mth1: function (callback) {

   //----need to wrap to something
   setTimeout(function () { 
      console.log("1");
      // be sure it is a function
      if (callback&& getType.toString.call(callback) == '[object Function]';) {
        // call it
        callback();
      }
   }, 1000);

   console.log('2');

}
```

Comment: Still have the same result: 2;3;1

Comment: sorry i did not see the part *"What I need: 2, 1, 3"*. You can make the call to the callback inside the function of the setTimeout. Juts make sure, as my answer shows, to check "callback" is executable function so your code does not break if an invalid callback is passed as a parameter.